# Docker + NGINX + SSL Termination

Tags: docker, nginx

Im trying to set up NGINX within a Docker container so that it will perform SSL termination for traffic going to another container (tcp443 -> tcp3001).

However Im getting a 502 Bad Gateway from NGINX with the following error in the NGINX logs:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream
```

**Containers**

The following containers are running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
3b640f25af44        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   hopeful_swartz
f7b13bf2bdcd        ghost               "docker-entrypoint..."   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         127.0.0.1:3001->2368/tcp       zen_carson
```

**Port 3001 Test**

I can reach the backend server (container) on port 3001.

```
root@linode-server:~# curl -IL http://127.0.0.1:3001
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: /private/
Vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 31
Date: Sat, 07 Apr 2018 19:25:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2655
ETag: W/"a5f-wAxdmCnbgI8/PCwspg8GKWyhtRw"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sat, 07 Apr 2018 19:25:02 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

**NGINX Config**

```
worker_processes 5;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
  server {
      listen              443 ssl;
      ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/packetflow.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/packetflow.key;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host linode.packetflow.co.uk;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check this :
https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/30-how-to-use-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-docker.html

Comment: Have you tried to launch docker container with `--net=host` option? With this, docker engine does proxy between host and docker's launched them.

Comment: @Alex , --net-host option is dangerous , as it exposes all network settings to internal docker container

Comment: @Sohan, you're right, but consider that tt's a first and provisional solution, please. I'd start with this and when it works, I'd filter creating a concrete network or rules inside container. That's why I've told that in a comment, not in a final solution

Answer (score 8):

You have basic issue of reachability. When you have below in your Nginx Config

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
```

Your are saying that within the same nginx container another service is running at port `3001`. But the service is running in another container.

Next looking at your `docker ps` output

```
f7b13bf2bdcd        ghost               "docker-entrypoint..."   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         127.0.0.1:3001->2368/tcp       zen_carson
```

The port inside the container is `2368` and not `3001`. Now comes the part of launching the container so you know its address

If you are you launching your docker container through command line then you will launch the container like below

```
docker run -d --name ghost ghost
```

Then in your nginx config you will use

```
proxy_pass http://ghost:2368;
```

The better way is to actually through `docker-compose`. So you will create `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: 3
services:
  ghost
    build: ghost
    image: ghost
  web:
    build: web
    image: web
    ports:
      - 443:443
```

You should look at below link

https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

Answer (score 2):

If nginx configuration is in docker container , how you are able to proxy to other docker using 127.0.0.1:3001 (which is host machine port). Actually your bind to 127.0.0.1:3001  is to host machine.

Are you trying to curl from host machine and nginx config is in docker.

For a quick fix please use 172.17.0.1:3001 instead of  127.0.0.1:3001 . It will work if you didn't change anything in docker network adapter.

Comment: Thanks, but this didnt work. I went into the ghost container and was unable to reach 172.17.0.1:3001. From the browser I get a "504 Gateway Time-out".

Comment: Can you try  below commands from docker and please let me know the output.
"telnet 172.17.0.1 3001"
"curl 172.17.0.1:3001"

And below command from host 
"ifconfig docker0"

Comment: From which component? docker containers or host?

Comment: I had explained that first 2 commands from docker where nginx is running and third command from host

Comment: TBH looking at this more I dont belive inter docker communication on the default docker bridge is permitted.

Comment: By default you can connect to all dockers each other and hosts using default docker bridge network ( i,e 172.17.0.x ),

Answer (score 2):

this line `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001` in your NGINX Config is wrong, `zen_carson`  doesn't works on your Nginx container localhost!they are works on different hosts!

if you want to access to `zen_carson` container from `hopeful_swartz`, first and simplest way is to use [linking between containers](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/), and use link alias instead of localhost IP!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution can be to move the nginx to the base machine (install it and run in a daemon). The loadbalancing between images happens on the host and only the application runs in docker.

Other solution can be creating hostname for the node image to reach it from the other images. This way you have to install docker-compose or create a script that runs the docker images with a specific name.